# Building paths in SBT for the packageMappings of the sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, rpm, sbt-native-packager

I am very new to SBT and need to create a RPM package for one of my project. The RPM contains only 1 file, which is a one-jar created by the sbt-onejar plugin). I want to use sbt-native-packager plugin and have created a Packagin.scala file under the /project directory like this:

```
object Packaging {
  val settings: Seq[Setting[_]] = packagerSettings ++ deploymentSettings ++ mapGenericFilesToLinux ++ Seq(

    maintainer := "Team",
    packageSummary := "Summary",
    packageDescription := """Description""",

    mappings in Universal += {
      file("target/scala-2.10/projectname_2.10-0.1-one-jar.jar") -> "/opt/projectname/projectname-0.1.jar"
    },

    linuxPackageMappings in Rpm <+= (baseDirectory) map { _:File =>
      (packageMapping(file("target/scala-2.10/projectname_2.10-0.1-one-jar.jar") -> "/opt/projectname/projectname-0.1.jar")
        withUser "someusr" withGroup "somegroup" withPerms "0755")
    },

    name in Rpm := "projectname",
    version in Rpm <<= version apply { sv => sv split "[^\\d]" filterNot (_.isEmpty) mkString "." },
    rpmRelease := "1",
    rpmVendor := "Vendor",
    rpmUrl := Some("url"),
    rpmGroup := Some("group"),
    rpmLicense := Some("BSD")
  )
}
```

1) I don't want to hardcode the file names. Instead of having `"target/scala-2.10/projectname_2.10-0.1-one-jar.jar"` I need a way to use existing SettingKey's, i.e. `target + "scala-" + scalaVersion + "/" + name + "_" + scalaVersion  + "-" + version + "-one-jar.jar"` - how do you do this=

2) For the value `rpmRelease := "1"` I want to use a System property, i.e. in Maven I would do `${rpm.buildNumber}`, how does that work in SBT?

3) Is there anything I should do better in regards to the sbt-native-packager plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You should always use *task output* in sbt rather than raw filesystem lookups.  Because sbt has parallel execution, if you don't put an explicit dependency on the output of a task, then you have no guarantee that a file will be created before you run your task.

In that vein you want to change your package mappings line to be something like this:

```
mappings in Universal += {
  oneJar.value -> "/opt/projectname/projectname-0.1.jar"
},
```

Where the `oneJar` key is defined in the [onejar plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/retronym/SbtOneJar.scala#L11).

2) Sbt just uses scala for the build language, so you can grab system properties similarly (but please also provide a default):

```
rpmRelease := Option(sys.props("rpm.buildNumber")) getOrElse "1"
```

3) Right now you're defining a generic package *and* redefining the same file in the Rpm with a different user.  The `mapGenericFilesToLinux` settings still lack a few customizations, but if you're not creating universal distributions, you should be able to drop that bit of settings and instead directly configure your linux package:

```
linuxPackageMappings in Rpm <+= (oneJar) map { jar:File =>
  (packageMapping(jar -> "/opt/projectname/projectname-0.1.jar")
    withUser "someusr" withGroup "somegroup" withPerms "0755")
},
```

Comment: Hmm as for `rpmRelease` I realized our build server Bamboo uses environment variables. So I tried changing it to `rpmRelease := Option(sys.env("rpm.buildNumber")) getOrElse "1"` in _project/Packaging.scala_ but for some reason I always get "1" returned. When I access `sys.env("rpm.buildNumber")` in build.sbt it works. For some reason environment variables are not propagated into Packaging.scala it seems.

Comment: hmm, that should be the case.   Setting ordering matters.  DO you have `rpmRelease := ...` somewhere else, or are you setting the native packager settings *after* your own rpmRelease setting?

Also `project/*.scala` settings are pulled before `build.sbt` settings.