# SBT rpm:package-bin fails with config not found error

Tags: scala, sbt, rpm, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to integrate rpmPlugin in Build.scala, but it seems it is failing to identify rpm config. Following is how my config looks in Build.scala

```
enablePlugins(RpmPlugin)
lazy val packageSettings =  Seq(
  packageName in Rpm := "noname",
  version in Rpm := "1.0.0",
  rpmRelease in Rpm := Some("1"),
  packageArchitecture in Rpm := "noArch",
  packageSummary := "zyx",
  packageDescription := "zyx",
  rpmVendor  := "zyx",
  rpmUrl := "zyx",
  rpmLicense := "zyx"
)
```

I also have following in plugin.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.3")
```

and following are imports in build.scala

```
import Keys._
import sbtassembly.AssemblyKeys._
import scoverage.ScoverageSbtPlugin.ScoverageKeys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager.autoImport._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.rpm.RpmPlugin
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.JavaServerAppPackaging
```

With all this information when I run rpm package command... I get following error (multiple of these error)

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/vikrant/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[error] /home/vikrant/project/Build.scala:46: not found: value rpmRelease
[error]     rpmRelease := Some("1"),
[error]     ^
[error] /home/vikrant/project/Build.scala:48: not found: value packageArchitecture
[error]     packageArchitecture in Rpm := "noArch",
[error]     ^
[error] /home/vikrant/project/Build.scala:54: not found: value rpmVendor
[error]     rpmVendor  := "zyx",
[error]     ^
[error] /home/vikrant/project/Build.scala:56: not found: value rpmUrl
[error]     rpmUrl := "zyx",
[error]     ^
[error] /home/vikrant/project/Build.scala:58: not found: value rpmLicense
[error]     rpmLicense := "zyx"
[error]     ^
[error] 5 errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Please advise what I can possibly do to get rid of this error. Documentation     is not very helpful and seems to be written for Buid.sbt usages.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently from the documentation ( http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/rpm.html#settings ), it seems that you only need to specify `rpmRelease` rather than `rpmRelease in Rpm`.

For an example check here:

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/test-project-play-rpm/packaging.sbt

And also this question:

[Building paths in SBT for the packageMappings of the sbt-native-packager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429906/building-paths-in-sbt-for-the-packagemappings-of-the-sbt-native-packager)

Comment: Infact thats what I started with... but it was not working as well. I am adding more details in question.

Comment: You may want to file an issue if its not already filed here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+rpm

Answer (score 0):

It seems this feature is strict about order we put the configuration. 
When everything else failed I tries playing with order of configuration.. and following worked.

```
version in Rpm := "1.0.0",
maintainer := "someValue",
packageArchitecture in Rpm := ""someValue"",
packageSummary in Rpm := ""someValue"",
packageDescription in Rpm := ""someValue"",
packageName in Linux := ""someValue"",
rpmRelease := "1",
rpmVendor := ""someValue"",
rpmLicense := Some(""someValue"")
```

For sure it may not be  right way to fix it... but it unblocked me. Going to open an issue with SBT though.

Comment: I would recommend not using `Build.scala` anymore. Instead try to put the settings into your `build.sbt` and custom logic into `AutoPlugins`. There are some limitations with `Build.scala` and `AutoPlugins`